# About addition processing in Metal

Tags: swift, metal

In WebGL (OpenGL), write as follows

```
// alpha blending
gl.blendFuncSeparate (gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE);

gl.bindFramebuffer (gl.FRAMEBUFFER, buffers [0] .framebuffer);
gl.useProgram (firstProgram);
webgl.enableAttribute (planeVBO, attLocation, attStride);
gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeIBO);
gl.uniform2fv (resolution, [width, height]);
gl.drawElements (gl.TRIANGLES, plane.index.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I am worried when I want to realize with Metal. In WebGL, if you read (bind) the created frame buffer and draw it with Shader, it will add it, but in the case of Metal
Is it more appropriate to send the framebuffer as a texture to Shader and add it on the Shader side rather than reading it? Or does it exist as a mechanism in the same way?
Or

```
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = renderTargetTexture

renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
```

Is it possible to continue adding in the same way as long as it is not cleared in such a place?
Or the earlier pipline

```
 renderTargetTexture = mtlDevice.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)
```

Since it has been initialized at that point, is there any need for change?

The code template itself is as follows.
https://sgaworks.com/metalsample/MetalSample2.zip

Comment: You want to avoid CPU-GPU (and reverse) synchronization as much as possible.  My rule of thumb is that once I'm on the GPU, I prefer to do as much of the computation as I can there, especially if passing additional data is cheap.  So the additional work can be done in your fragment shader, yes do it there.

Comment: Also you can encode multiple commands to a single MTLCommandBuffer and commit them at once (so you can do one RenderPassEncoder, then another, then another).  If some need intermediate results from another, and you don't need it on the CPU for anything else, put those in a GPU-private `MTLTexture` or `MTLBuffer`, so you don't pay the cost of synchronizing those with the CPU.

Comment: There is some limit to how many commands you can encode at once... not such much a limit on the number as a limit on how long they take to work.   You can encode so much work on one `MTLCommandBuffer` that it will time-out producing a Metal error that you can inspect if you set a `completedHandler`.

Comment: If you want it to not clear and only add instead, change the load action from `.clear` to `.load`.

Comment: Thank you.

`renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor ()
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [0] .texture = renderTargetTexture
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [0] .loadAction = .load
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [0] .storeAction = .store`

By doing so, it is possible to add to what was once rendered in the buffer and read out with Shader.